# Excel Index Match - Pairing a set of random values corresponding to a range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, match, criteria

In the following data, I would like to use columns **L** and **M** in order to pair with matches between **A**,**B** and **C**,**D** respectively.

[image: Sample Picture]

To be more precise, I would like `Serial Number A`: **10 - SUV** to match `Serial Number: B` **10 - Car**. If any of these combinations do not match, I should be getting a red flag. For instance, `Serial Number A`: **40**, cannot take the value "Sedan." It would have to be either "**Road Bike**" or "**Mountain Bike**" according to the pair values in columns **L** and **M**, respectively.

I was thinking a double match would work, however, I am not sure how to tackle this issue.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think I have finally wrapped my head around what you are trying to do.  Tell me if I am on the right track.  You want to sort columns C:D using column C as the key (so that the ids in columns A and C are aligned).  Then you want to compare the values in columns B and D of each row to see whether there is a match in columns L and M of any row.

Comment: Or, without actually sorting C:D, you want to do something like `=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,C:D,2,FALSE)=VLOOKUP(B2,L:M,2,FALSE),"Red flag","good")`

Comment: Hi @ashleedawg. Thank you for your assistance. Your logic is right. However, when applying your formula, the results are inverted. I am getting "good" for row 4 of  column A Serial number 40. This was solved by inverting the true/false argument. Another observation is, I need to get the "red flag"/"good indication" for items referring in column C, not A. For instance, Column C Serial number 40 should be "red flag" since the corresponding serial number in Column A does not match the pairing values in Columns L and M, respectively.

Comment: In that case use, because you know that the `VLOOKUP(A2,C:D,2,FALSE)` in my original formula is `D2`, and you know that the `B2` in my original formula can be obtained using `VLOOKUP(C2,A:B,FALSE,2)`, then you can revise the formula to be `=IF(D2=VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(C2,A:B,2,FALSE),L:M,2,FALSE),"good","Red flag")`.  (And, sorry, I realised I had the "red flag"/"good" reversed as soon as I woke up this morning so logged in to point it out - but it looks like you worked it out yourself.)

Comment: @Jim-ExcelNewbie - I think you meant to thank **yowe3k**  :-)

Comment: @YowE3K thank you for your valuable input and support. It gave me a better understanding of how things work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a chance to debug the code example I wrote, so here is the working product.

I think what you need is to build an array of suitable responses for each selection, using something like:

```
Function GetKeys() As Variant
    'This function will obtain an array of suitable response keys that can be used to then check the values.
    Dim TmpArr As Variant
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Set Sht = Worksheets("[SheetName]") 'Replace [SheetName] with your actual sheer name.
    TmpArr = Sht.Range("L2:M" & Sht.Range("L" & Sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    TmpArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(TmpArr)
    Dim Arr() As String
    ReDim Arr(1 To 2, 1 To 1) As String
    Dim NoKeys As Integer, X As Integer, Y As Integer
    'This will fill the first dimension of the array with the unique values from Column M
    Arr(1, 1) = LCase(CStr(TmpArr(2, 1)))
    For X = 2 To UBound(TmpArr, 2)
        For Y = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2)
            If LCase(CStr(TmpArr(2, X))) = Arr(1, Y) Then GoTo ExistsAlready
        Next Y
        ReDim Preserve Arr(1 To 2, 1 To (UBound(Arr, 2) + 1))
        Arr(1, UBound(Arr, 2)) = LCase(CStr(TmpArr(2, X)))
ExistsAlready:
    Next X
    'This now fills the second dimension of the array with a comma separated list of suitable values from Column L
    For X = 1 To UBound(TmpArr, 2)
        For Y = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2)
            If LCase(CStr(TmpArr(2, X))) = Arr(1, Y) Then
                    If Arr(2, Y) = "" Then
                            Arr(2, Y) = LCase(CStr(TmpArr(1, X)))
                        Else
                            Arr(2, Y) = Arr(2, Y) & ", " & LCase(TmpArr(1, X))
                    End If
                    Exit For
            End If
        Next Y
    Next X
    GetKeys = Arr
End Function
```

Then once you have that, you could check the list of values against that array, using something like:

```
Sub CheckValues()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim Keys As Variant
    'This calls the above function to obtain the list of suitable keys
    Keys = GetKeys
    Dim Set1 As Variant, Set2 As Variant
    Set Sht = Worksheets("[SheetName]")
    Set1 = Sht.Range("A2:B" & Sht.Range("A" & Sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    Set2 = Sht.Range("C2:D" & Sht.Range("C" & Sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    Set1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Set1)
    Set2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Set2)
    Dim X As Integer, Y As Integer, Z As Integer
    'This starts by looping through each row of data in Columns C:D and finds the corresponding key value from Column M
    For X = 1 To UBound(Set2, 2)
        For Y = 1 To UBound(Keys, 2)
            If LCase(CStr(Set2(2, X))) = CStr(Keys(1, Y)) Then
                    'Having Found the key from Column C:D, it now finds the value in Column A that matches C
                    For Z = 1 To UBound(Set1, 2)
                        'This checks whether the value in B is one of the suitable values from Column L and colours the cells if not
                        If Set2(1, X) = Set1(1, Z) Then
                                If Keys(2, Y) Like "*" & LCase(CStr(Set1(2, Z))) & "*" Then
                                        GoTo Found_It
                                    Else
                                        Sht.Range("A" & (Z + 1) & ":B" & (Z + 1)).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
                                        Sht.Range("C" & (X + 1) & ":D" & (X + 1)).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
                                        GoTo Found_It
                                 End If
                        End If
                    Next Z
            End If
        Next Y
Found_It:
    Next X
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Sercho. Thank you for your input time you put writing this code. For the first function, I am getting a syntax error in line: Arr(2, Y) = CStrTmpArr(1, X)). For sub "CheckValues" I am getting a syntax error in the following line: "If LCase(CStr(Set2(2, X))) = LCase(CStr(Keys(1,Y)) then". I will try to see what I can do about it, although, my VBA skills are not that great...

Comment: @Jim-ExcelNewbie I’m glad the code works. Though you should mark this answer as correct now, in order to prevent others from wasting time trying to provide a solution to a solved problem.